# Changing color or image of marker that are not clustered in android

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I want to chnage the color of marker that are not being clustered and shown as an individual marker on map.
I tried code from a demo project from android but I am not able get it working in my code.I change icon for one marker it chnaged everywhere and cluster disappears.
Here is the original code which I was trying to use
(Only relevant part from the code)

```
public class CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity extends BaseDemoActivity implements ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<Person>, ClusterManager.OnClusterInfoWindowClickListener<Person>, ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<Person>, ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<Person> {
private ClusterManager<Person> mClusterManager;
private Random mRandom = new Random(1984);

/**
 * Draws profile photos inside markers (using IconGenerator).
 * When there are multiple people in the cluster, draw multiple photos (using MultiDrawable).
 */
private class PersonRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<Person> {
    private final IconGenerator mIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getApplicationContext());
    private final IconGenerator mClusterIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getApplicationContext());
    private final ImageView mImageView;
    private final ImageView mClusterImageView;
    private final int mDimension;

    public PersonRenderer() {
        super(getApplicationContext(), getMap(), mClusterManager);

        View multiProfile = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.multi_profile, null);
        mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(multiProfile);
        mClusterImageView = (ImageView) multiProfile.findViewById(R.id.image);

        mImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        mDimension = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_image);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mDimension, mDimension));
        int padding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_padding);
        mImageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        mIconGenerator.setContentView(mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(Person person, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        // Draw a single person.
        // Set the info window to show their name.
        mImageView.setImageResource(person.profilePhoto);
        Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(person.name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<Person> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        // Draw multiple people.
        // Note: this method runs on the UI thread. Don't spend too much time in here (like in this example).
        List<Drawable> profilePhotos = new ArrayList<Drawable>(Math.min(4, cluster.getSize()));
        int width = mDimension;
        int height = mDimension;

        for (Person p : cluster.getItems()) {
            // Draw 4 at most.
            if (profilePhotos.size() == 4) break;
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(p.profilePhoto);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            profilePhotos.add(drawable);
        }
        MultiDrawable multiDrawable = new MultiDrawable(profilePhotos);
        multiDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

        mClusterImageView.setImageDrawable(multiDrawable);
        Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
    }
```

Can anyone simplify or explain the process how this works

This is the code for onBeforeClusterRendered which I found after decompiling DefaultClusterRender class

```
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<T> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    int bucket = this.getBucket(cluster);
    BitmapDescriptor descriptor = (BitmapDescriptor)this.mIcons.get(bucket);
    if(descriptor == null) {
        this.mColoredCircleBackground.getPaint().setColor(this.getColor(bucket));
        descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(this.mIconGenerator.makeIcon(this.getClusterText(bucket)));
        this.mIcons.put(bucket, descriptor);
    }

    markerOptions.icon(descriptor);
}
```

But I can't understand a thing from this.